# Docker Image DynamoDB unable to open database file

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to run the docker image of the AWS DynamoDB service using a local volume to store data.  When I try to create my first table I am getting the following order repeating until eventually the script fails.

```
dynamodb-local           | Aug 31, 2022 3:32:49 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
dynamodb-local           | WARNING: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[shared-local-instance.db]: stopped abnormally, reincarnating in 3000ms
dynamodb-local           | Aug 31, 2022 3:32:52 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
dynamodb-local           | WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[5]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [14] unable to open database file
dynamodb-local           | Aug 31, 2022 3:32:52 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
dynamodb-local           | SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[shared-local-instance.db]: error running job queue
dynamodb-local           | com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [14] unable to open database file
dynamodb-local           |      at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1480)
dynamodb-local           |      at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
dynamodb-local           |      at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
dynamodb-local           |      at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
dynamodb-local           |      at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
dynamodb-local           |      at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
dynamodb-local           |      at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
dynamodb-local           |      at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
dynamodb-local           |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

My docker-compose file is based on the one from AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.consumer
    ports:
      - "5558:5558"
    depends_on:
      - "dynamodb-local"
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'DUMMYIDEXAMPLE'
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'DUMMYEXAMPLEKEY'

  dynamodb-local:
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "data:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal



volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
  data: {}
```

Below is the table I am creating

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


TABLE_NAME = "check_tbl"
dynamodb = boto3.client(
            'dynamodb',
            region_name="us-east-1",
            aws_access_key_id="dummy_access_key",
            aws_secret_access_key="dummy_secret_key",
            endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000",
        )

try:
    response = dynamodb.describe_table(TableName=TABLE_NAME)

except ClientError as ce:
    if ce.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
        result = dynamodb.create_table(
            TableName=TABLE_NAME,
                KeySchema=[
                    {
                        'AttributeName': 'id',
                        'KeyType': 'HASH'  # Partition key
                    }
                ],
                AttributeDefinitions=[
                    {
                        'AttributeName': 'timestamp',
                        'AttributeType': 'D'
                    }
                ],
                ProvisionedThroughput={
                    'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
                    'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
                }
            )

    else:
        print("Unknown exception occurred while querying for the " + TABLE_NAME + " table. Printing full error:")
        pprint(ce.response)
```

My volumes path (/var/lib/docker/volumes/data) is owned by root, but that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: What   `docker inspect -f "{{json .Mounts}}" dynamodb-local | jq .` outputs?   Read https://blog.container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker

Comment: That was it.  It was defaulting to ./docker/dynamodb.  Curious it ignored the volume, however, once that path was created and was 777, it worked.  Thansk for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and it was solved by adding my user to the folder created by the image:

```
sudo chown $user -R docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you needed to add a dot slash at the beginning of your volumes

```
volumes:
  - "./data:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
```

Then as @Hernando Correa said, if you are running docker with sudo and didn't create that ./data directory before running docker first, then docker creates that directory where your user doesn't have write permissions. And therefore you can fix by running this in the directory where your compose is:

```
sudo chown Brian:Brian -R data
```

Or making sure any directories used in volumes are created by you first, before running docker compose